# Incorrect ordering of associated Rails model when using will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate, pagination

I'm having problems ordering with the will_paginate plugin. Here are my models

Forum

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :topics, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :posts, :through => :topics
```

Topic

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :forum, :counter_cache => true
    has_many :posts, :dependent => :delete_all
```

Post

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :topic, :counter_cache => true
    belongs_to :user
```

I'm trying to get the topics which have the most recent posts. The following works correctly:

```
forum = Forum.find(3)
forum.topics.all(:include => [:posts], :order => "posts.created_at DESC")
```

But when introducing pagination (using the will_paginate plugin) the ordering is incorrect.

```
forum = Forum.find(3)
forum.topics.paginate(:include => [:posts], :order => "posts.created_at DESC", :page => page)
```

Does anybody know why use of the will_paginate plugin could be detrimentally affecting ordering?

I'm using Rails 2.3.9 and will_paginate 1.6.2.

Comment: Have you tried :include-ing the topics in the paginate?

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3, I think you can move the ordering to before the paginate call:

```
forum.topics.includes(:posts).order("posts.created_at DESC").paginate()
```

Comment: Using Rails 2.3.9 unfortunately. Do you know how this would be achieved with Rails 2?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use square brackets in *:include*.
Also add *:per*_ *page* parameter:

```
forum = Forum.find(3)
forum.topics.paginate(
        :per_page => 5,
        :page     => page,
        :include  => :posts,
        :order    => "posts.created_at DESC")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid those changes didn't fix the ordering problem